# US to Canada and back again 2 weeks before passport expires?

Tags: usa, passports, canada

I will be traveling to Canada with my husband for 3 days to celebrate our anniversary in mid November. Our passports are due to expire 1.5 weeks after the date we plan on returning back to the US. Will we be able to take our trip? Renewing our passport and get it quickly will be too expensive for us. Will we be able to get into Canada and back home?

Comment: Can you prove that you will leave Canada before your passport expires?  ie plane ticket, train ticket etc.

Comment: we are driving across the border - perhaps a printout of our hotel reservations would be all I could provide.

Comment: There is no minimum time of validity required, but the border officials maybe concerned about its expiration and your stay, since you can not re-enter the USA with an expired passport.

Comment: We return with about 1.5 weeks left before our passports expires, both my husband's and mine will expire together on the same date.

Comment: @Tom: "since you can not re-enter the USA with an expired passport." Of course you can, if you are a U.S. citizen.

Comment: Just sayin' - no you cannot enter the US on an expired US passport even if you are a US citizen. I have found several places on the internet that says this to be true....who knew? I would never have guessed that to be so. I am calling a US Passport Center tomorrow to find out that for sure.

Comment: If your passport expires while outside the USA you need to visit an embassy or consulate and obtain a temporary passport to travel back to the USA.

Comment: @lsienna: That is not true. A U.S. citizen who arrives at a U.S. border, who can satisfactorily prove their U.S. citizenship, cannot be denied entry to the U.S. no matter what. It doesn't matter if they bad-mouth the U.S. or refuse to answer their questions or don't have a particular document. They can enter, period.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [U.S. Department of State's information on visiting Canada](http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/english/country/canada.html), the only restriction on passport expiration for visiting Canada is that the passport must be valid at the time of entry. That page also lists the contact information for the U.S. Embassy in Ottawa. It might not be a bad idea to either shoot them an e-mail or give them a call just to make sure they don't think you'll get hassled at the border, since 1.5 weeks is cutting it very close as passports go.